# read-sequence-no-hangの実装

Tags: common-lisp

read-char-no-hangのシークエンス版 read-sequence-no-hangを作りたいのですが、可能でしょうか。

一番、シンプルな実装は以下のようなものになると思います。

```
(defun read-sequence-no-hang (seq stream &rest rest)
  (when (listen stream)
    (apply #'read-sequence seq stream rest)))
```

しかし、上記のような実装では、読み込み不可能な状態(ストリーム中にデータは存在しないがEOFではない状態)と、EOFを区別できません。
かといって、read-char-no-hangをシークエンスのサイズ分繰り返すような実装なら、EOF判定が可能だと思われますが、効率が悪そうです（加えてあんまり美しくもありません）。

可能ならCommon lispの仕様の範囲で実装できたらいいと思います。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 試してないのでコメントですが、1文字分少なめにread-sequenceして、その後read-char-no-hangする、というのではだめですか。

Comment: shirokさん、ご回答ありがとうございます。
確かにcharactor stream の場合はそれで出来そうですね。
少し質問はずれますがCommon LispでEOF判定したい場合、shirokさんのようにread-char(-no-hang)を呼び出すのが一般的なのでしょうか？

Comment: ソケットやパイプ、ターミナルなど「EOFでないけれどデータが直ちにavailableでない場合があり、ブロックせずに両者を区別したい」という用途には、そもそもストリームは不適切な抽象化だと思います。なので可能ならより上層のレイヤで設計を見直すなり、下層をノンブロッキングI/Oのフレームワークに任せるなりすると思います。ポータブルなライブラリで何とかしなくちゃならないという場合は元々無理な要求なので多少コードが汚くなっても気にしないかなと思います。

Comment: shirokさん、勉強になりました。設計のレベルから見直してみることにします。加えて申し訳ありませんが、「ノンブロッキングI/Oのフレームワーク」の内、socket関連のもので、何かおすすめのものがあれば、ご紹介いただいてもよろしいでしょうか？